# zero-mean RV $$ with finite fourth moment, probability of being positive

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation, upper-lower-bounds

For zero-mean RV $X$ with finite fourth moment, prove that 
$$
P(X>0)\ge \frac{\mathbb{E}(X^2)^2}{4\mathbb{E}(X^4)}
$$

I tried Chebyshev with adding $t$ to both sides, but I could not get forth moment.

Comment: The Paley-Zygmund inequality (see [here][1], page 16) gives that for any non-negative random variable $Z$ with finite variance and any $\theta\in(0,1)$ we have
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[Z \geq \theta\cdot\mathbb{E}[Z]\right]\geq (1-\theta)^2\frac{\left(\mathbb{E}[Z]\right)^2}{\mathbb{E}[Z^2]} $$
hence by picking $\theta=\frac{1}{2}$ and $Z=X^2$ we get
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[X^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}\,\mathbb{E}[X^2]\right]\geq \frac{\left(\mathbb{E}[X^2]\right)^2}{4\,\mathbb{E}[X^4]} $$
so it is enough to show that $\mathbb{P}[X\geq 0]\geq\mathbb{P}[|X|\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sigma(X)]$.

Comment: However, I am not sure the last inequality holds.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It does not hold in general: for $X=\pm 1$ w.p. $1/2$, $\sigma(X)=1$ and $\mathbb P(|X|\geq 1/\sqrt{2})=1$ while l.h.s. is $1/2$.

Comment: Do not cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331019/zero-mean-rv-x-probability-of-being-positive-using-moments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331019/zero-mean-rv-x-probability-of-being-positive-using-moments (already answered).